# Are there graduate programs available specific to one programming language?

Tags: career-path, computer-science

I am a Java enthusiast.  I only know Java and its frameworks (like `struts2`, `spring`), and would like to pursue a graduate degree in only Java. Are there any graduate programs that are specific to a single programming language, such as this?

Comment: I am no computer scientist, but this sounds to me like somebody asking about getting a medicine-related degree without ever having to deal with something other than noses.

Comment: If you know Java well, you should be able to pick up a new language within a year. Find a major project, like maintaining a friend or organization's website or an internship in a language other than Java, and you'll pick up the new language and frameworks pretty quickly.

Comment: I am also a Java enthusiast. In the late 1960's, when I started learning to program, I was a Fortran enthusiast. If I had only learned Fortran, without acquiring the tools and mental flexibility to learn programming languages as needed, I would not have had the option of learning Java. For the sake of your long term career, learn at least one other language before you become too locked in, and cannot wrap your mind around anything other than Java.

Comment: Two words: Smart Grid

Comment: Even if there are graduate programs focused specifically on Java (I'd assume there aren't), I can't believe this would be a sensible criterion to filter on as anything but a tie breaker.  Surely it's much more important to do work you are excited by, in a location you like, with a great peer group and advisor.

Comment: It's not a graduate program, but you can have a look at getting the [Oracle Java certification](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=653&get_params=p_id:333#tabs-1-3&intcmp=WWOUCERTTOPBAN4JAVA).

Comment: I have generalized this question, such that the main reason for closure no longer might no longer apply.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's even worse, it's like somebody asking about getting a medicine degree using only stethoscopes. In (most of) computer science, programming languages are a tool, and the real focus is on algorithms or higher abstractions.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I agree with this analogy, more than with the noses one. As opposed to [what some tv shows and movies](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OpenHeartDentistry) [would have us believe](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuperDoc), medical doctors typically do specialize on some comparably narrow field like "noses" (or, in other words, I know why I typically have to go to three different places if I want to get a treatment for my teeth, my eyes, and my throat, not just to one "head doctor").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Not that I claim that my analogy is perfect or better than the stethoscope analogy, but medical doctors have to do a lot of basic medical training before they eventually specialise on noses or whatever (at least where I am from), which is a very good thing, since the human body is not modular.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the early 20th century, MIT faced a crisis: it's graduates, though well trained, were rapidly becoming obsolete.  In response, the university launched [a long-running series of curriculum reforms](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27757693) that changed it from essentially a training school that taught the *practices* of engineering to instead focus on teaching the *scientific principles* underlying those practices, with knowledge about the specific practices of the day as a byproduct.

I bring this up because there is a close parallel to your question: you ask whether there are any graduate programs dedicated specifically to Java.  Maybe there are, but **they would be a waste of time and money.**  If you want vocational training in specific things about Java, there are lots of free resources online.  If you want an education that will let you use Java at a deeper level, you want a curriculum that is not dedicated to a particular technology du jour.  The foundations of computer science cut across programming languages and platforms.  Maybe you will happen to find a graduate program where most of the classes happen to use Java, but it might well change tomorrow.

Moreover, you may find it difficult to be taken seriously in either the corporate or academic world if you declare an unwavering loyalty to a single programming language or other technology.  There are lots of Java shops out there who will be happy to have people experienced in the language, but when somebody says they know only a single programming language, that is typically a major red flag.  Most good programmers have had cause or curiosity enough to at least dabble in many languages, and people who claim to be experts limited to precisely one programming language typically turn out to be [Dunning-Kruger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) victims.  Maybe you're different, but you'll likely have quite a bit of well-justified skepticism to overcome.

Comment: I've a similar answer. Here's my addendum: As you become older, you may laugh at your unwavering loyalty to a particular technology in your younger days. In my grade school days, Visual-(whatever) was hot as Java was coming along.  At the university, the students complained why the classes were not taught in VB.  VB still exists, but not very hot any more and I still have 30+ years of career ahead of me (hopefully) before retirement!